# Getting list of app specific process in a multi process app in android

Tags: java, android, process

My application is running two `Processes` one for the all `Services` and another for the  other components.

I want to get all the process of the my application. However I am able to get list of all processes running on the device and then filtering for mine app's processes. But I want to be directly app specific. I think there should must be way to get the app specific processes.

Thanks in advance for the answer.

Comment: you can create it by your self first get list of all running processes then compare if the process package name is your app package name